# Can we extract text up to the first inner <br/> (if it exists) using InnerText?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

Take this HTML (multiline for clarity):

```
<li style="list-style-image: url('lib/10.bmp')" class="rvps2">
    <span class="rvts15">Internal: Updated </span>
    <span class="rvts16">Google Calendar Interface</span>
    <span class="rvts15">Nuget Packages:</span>
    <br/>
    <span class="rvts15"></span>
    <br/>
    <span class="rvts15">Google.Apis.1.49.0 -&gt; Google.Apis.1.50.0</span>
    <br/>
    <span class="rvts15">Google.Apis.Auth.1.49.0 -&gt; Google.Apis.Auth.1.50.0</span>
    <br/>
    <span class="rvts15">Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.1.49.0.2187 -&gt; Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.1.50.0.2237</span>
    <br/>
    <span class="rvts15">Google.Apis.Core.1.49.0 -&gt; Google.Apis.Core.1.50.0</span>
    <br/>
    <span class="rvts15">NLog.4.7.6 -&gt; NLog.4.7.8</span>
    <br/>
    <span class="rvts15">NLog.Config.4.7.6 -&gt; NLog.Config.4.7.8</span>
    <br/>
    <span class="rvts15">NLog.Schema.4.7.6 -&gt; NLog.Schema.4.7.8</span>
</li>
```

I can't change the structure of the HTML. Using the HTML Agility Pack I currently have this code for the `li` item:

```
writer.WriteString(listitem.InnerText.Trim());
```

The problem is that `InnerText` returns everything and I don't want that.

- If the `li` item has `<br/>` elements then I only want to include the first line of text. In this case:

> Internal: Update Google Calendar Interface Nuget Packages:

- For other `li` items that don't have any `<br/>` elements then it is fine using `InnerText`.

Can we extract text as a string up to the first `<br/>` (if it exists)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would imagine it's straightforward. Enumerate `ChildNodes` of `li`, take their `InnerText`, concatenate the strings with a single space as delimiter, stop at first `br`.

Maybe you were asking if there is a ready made function, so this can be done without this special code, but I would imagine there is not.

---

Sample code:

```
string itemtext = string.Empty;
foreach(HtmlNode item in listitem.ChildNodes)
{
    // We are only interested in "span" elements
    if(item.Name == "span")
    {
        itemtext += item.InnerText.Trim();
        itemtext += " ";
    }

    // Stop at the first "br" element.
    if (item.Name == "br")
        break;
}

writer.WriteString(itemtext.Trim().Replace(" .", "."));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Based on your suggestion I have been able to handle this issue. Do you mind if I add my code to your answer for others benefit? You can tweak it if you want.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle sure, go ahead.

Comment: Done. I had to cater for issue with "." getting a space inserted in sentences.